# Numpy savetxt loop

Tags: for-loop, numpy, save, arrays

Using Numpy, I am going to split an array of dimension `(557124,2)`, `dtype = "S10"`, in 6 subarrays using:

```
sub_arr = np.split(arr, 6)
```

Now I would like to use a `for` loop on `savetxt` and save the 6 subarrays to 6 .txt files.

I tried:

```
for i in sub_array:
    np.savetxt(("Subarray", i, ".txt"), sub_array[i], fmt='%s')
```

There are 2 problems:

1. It's incorrect to say `in sub_array`. I should use `range(5)` but I want to make it adaptable to any number of sub arrays.
2. I thought I could use a sort of "paste" as in R when I did `("Subarray", i, ".txt")`. Is there anything alike in Numpy?

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've understood

```
sub_arr = np.split(arr, 6)
```

returns a list of 6 numpy arrays. Then you can use enumerate to get each array and its index

```
fname_template = "Subarray.{i}.txt"
for i, sarr in enumerate(sub_arr):
    np.savetxt(fname_template.format(i=i), sarr, fmt='%s')
```

To create the file name I've used the [new string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples). Otherwise you can concatenate strings with `+` as `"Subarray."+str(i)+".txt"`, but you have to make sure that all the elements that you concatenate are strings.

Comment: If you are not familiar with iterators you can also give a look at [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Comment: Do you know how I could do the opposite to read files in a loop? E.g. file.1, file.2... file.23 and keep them all in memory without creating a 3D array? Thank you!

Comment: if you mean reading from files and save in a list of arrays you can do something like `sub_array = [np.loadtxt(fname_template.format(i=i)) for i in range(23)]`. If you want to save then in a contiguous 2D array you can then use [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

Comment: ..pensare che ci son stata tutto il giorno.. vabeh sto imparando! Grazie appena ho 15 "reputation" ti do un voto!